# Why doesn't this simple partial recurrence equation work in mathematica?

Tags: difference-equations

I have the following recurrence equation:

```
L[t_, alpha_] := 
 Min[2*epsilon[t, alpha] - x[t, alpha], x[t, alpha - 1]]

epsilon[t_, alpha_] := alpha^2

d[t_] := 10

f = 10

RSolve[{x[t, alpha] == x[t - 1, alpha] + L[t - 1, alpha] - L[t - 1, alpha + 1], 
    x[0, alpha] == 0, 
    x[t, f] == x[t - 1, f] + L[t - 1, f] - d[t - 1]},
    x[t, alpha], {t, alpha}]
```

It simply outputs the code from RSolve[... onwards, without giving any errors.

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong:
I'm giving an initial condition:

```
x[0, alpha] == 0
```

and a boundary condition on alpha:

```
x[t, f] == x[t - 1, f] + L[t - 1, f] - d[t - 1]}
```

Why doesn't mathematica solve this?

Comment: "Why doesn't *Mathematica* solve this?" - possibly because the closed form (if it does have one) is not necessarily known to *Mathematica*.

Comment: "partical"?????

Comment: "partial"**, sorry.

Comment: I see. I did not know that RSolve necessarily calculated a closed form solution. That solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want values you don't need `RSolve`

```
epsilon[t_, alpha_] = alpha^2
L[t_, alpha_] := 
 Min[2*epsilon[t, alpha] - x[t, alpha], x[t, alpha - 1]]
f = 10
x[0, alpha_] = 0
d[t_] = 10
x[t_, f] := x[t - 1, f] + L[t - 1, f] - d[t - 1]
x[t_, alpha_] := 
 x[t - 1, alpha] + L[t - 1, alpha] - L[t - 1, alpha + 1]
Table[ x[t, a] , {t, 0, 5}, {a, 15}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]